# SoapClient ExecuteQuery fails the second time

Tags: php, soap, localhost, simplexml, soap-client

When I run this method the first time, it works fine, but the second time, I get these warnings and errors:

Warning: SoapClient::__call(): Memory allocation failed : growing buffer

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Sender] looks like we got no XML document

When I "provision", it works fine again once.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);

$xmlQuery = '<Query>
    <Select languages="'.$language.'">
        <Feature id="*"/>
    </Select>
    <From id="Product"/>
    <Where>
        <Clause id="AppType" operator="!=" value="" />
        <Clause id="MainGroup" operator="!=" value="" />
    </Where>
</Query>';

$request = 'http://localhost:8080/Products/getdata.asmx?wsdl';

$options = [
    'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,
    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'connection_timeout'=>15,
    'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
    'exceptions'=>true,
];

$soap = new \SoapClient($request, $options);
$res = $soap->ExecuteQuery(['query' => $xmlQuery]);
$re = new \SimpleXMLElement($res->ExecuteQueryResult);
```

I thought I have cleared the cache with WSDL caches, but it seems that it does not do the job.
Can anyone explain what is going on here, and a fix to this problem?
Is there probably a way to split up this request and do this "chunk-wise"?

I am getting around 30 000 products from the request.

Is it wrong to use $soap->ExecuteQuery? Can't seem to find much information about it.

Comment: What PHP version and [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) size?

Comment: PHP version 7.2 and memory_limit size is 1024M. Had 512M before,, but just changed it to 1024M to test. Still the same.. @camelsWriteInCamelCase

Comment: I have tried to use unset($res), but not working either

Answer (score 0):

1) Use REST.

2) Maybe it would be better and easier to send all products data as 1 archived CSV file?

3) `WSDL_CACHE_NONE` may not work in some cases. Try to disable SOAP caching by adding the following configuration options at the beginning of your script:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0'); 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0');
```

Option `'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` can be useful.

4) If items 1-3 are not suitable, try to add a pagination for the response data. 30 000 products - it is very much, several hundred products for one page per one response will be quite enough.

Comment: Tested 3, getting the same errors. I dont know how to use 1, 2 or 3, sorry. Can you help further with it?

Comment: I am not very good at this, kinda new to me @camelWriteInCamelCase

Comment: There are a lot of articles on the Internet about this. If you have any specific questions, ask them and the community on this site will always help.